# Impersonating a thread using GSSAPI's established security context, on Windows

Tags: winapi, odbc, kerberos, gssapi, kerberos-delegation

I am working on enabling Kerberos authentication/delegation in my application.

My setup: The client is any web browser. The server runs on Windows and hosts some of my services, with Apache/Tomcat as the front end. The server can delegate work to one or more of my services on one or more machines. My services run in Java, but invoke C++ code via JNI and the C++ code makes the connection to the data sources (via ODBC for most relational data sources). Currently I am working on connecting to SQL Server via its ODBC driver.

I have mod_auth_kerb set up in Apache, and that is able to authenticate the user using Kerberos. My question: How do I use the established security context to impersonate the thread which will invoke the ODBC driver's SQLDriverConnect call? I have a working prototype that uses LogonUser and ImpersonateLoggedonUser API's to login a particular user (using her username and password) and impersonate her on the thread that invokes the  SQLDriverConnect call on the SQL Server ODBC driver. But I don't know how to use GSSAPI's established security context/delegated context (gss_ctx_id_t/gss_cred_id_t) to impersonate my thread. In other words, how do I convert the GSSAPI's handles into SSPI handles so that I can invoke ImpersonateSecurityContext or ImpersonateLoggedonUser or similar Win32 API's.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!
Ed